# Not getting WAIT_ABANDONED or WAIT_FAILED after exiting during wait

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, semaphore

I'm setting up some interprocess communication/memory sharing, and in the process, I'm trying to synchronize the initial setup of memory. I want my child process to wait for the parent process to finish - or if it fails, take over:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <coni
// o.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mutex.cpp"

#define LOG(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl

int _tmain() {
    HANDLE hSemaphore; // TODO: REFACTOR UNINITIALISED MEMORY

    std::string semaphoreName = std::string("test-semaphore");
    SetLastError(NULL);
    hSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(
            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL, // default security attributes
            0,
            LONG_MAX,
            semaphoreName.c_str() // named semaphore
    );

    if (hSemaphore == NULL) throw std::runtime_error("Failed to obtain mutex: " + semaphoreName);

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
        LOG("CHILD WAITING FOR SEMAPHORE");
        DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, 10000);
        if (result != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            switch (result) {
                case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                    LOG("WAIT TIMED OUT");
                    break;
                case WAIT_FAILED:
                    // mutex closed
                    LOG("WAIT FAILED: " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
                    break;
                case WAIT_ABANDONED:
                    // program holding mutex crashed / closed without closing mutex
                    LOG("WAIT ABANDONED");
                    break;
            }
            return 1;
        }

        LOG("CHILD AQUIRED SEMPAHORE");
        ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, 1, NULL);
        LOG("CHILD RELEASED SEMPAHORE");
        return 0;
    } else {
        LOG("SIMULATING LONG OPERATION - SLEEPING 5 SECONDS");
        Sleep(5000);
        LOG("OPERATION DONE");

//        LOG("RELEASING SEMPAHORE");
//        ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, 1, NULL);
//        LOG("RELEASED SEMPAHORE");
//
////      hold console-app
//        _getch();
        LOG("CLOSING SEMAPHORE HANDLE");
        CloseHandle(hSemaphore);
        LOG("SEMAPHORE HANDLE CLOSED");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've commented out the lines where the parent releases a semaphore and sleeps - and instead, I close the handle and exit.

What I expected is for the waiting process (started about a second after the parent process) to get an abandoned - or failed - error. Instead, it just times out. So, if I set the time out to `INFINITE` this program would indefinitely halt when the parent closed. Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour?

When I say parent and waiting process, I don't mean the waiting process is a sub-process of the parent; the parent came first (and created the semaphore) and the waiting process waits for the parent to release.

Comment: According to the [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject), `WAIT_ABANDONED` is only returned for mutex.

Comment: `WAIT FAILED` you got only in case you pass invalid handle  to `WaitForSingleObject` (not valid handle, not waitable object handle, no SYNCHRONIZE access for handle). that other side close self handle - have no any effect on your `WaitForSingleObject` . `WAIT_ABANDONED` is only returned for mutex.

Comment: @RbMm I'm using a mutex now, and `ReleaseMutex` does not wake up `WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, ...)`. Abandon is working now, thankfully

Comment: @RbMm After I free the mutex, I can't acquire it, It just times out everytime

Comment: The mutex is only able to be received on this process

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi "*I'm using a mutex now, and `ReleaseMutex` does not wake up `WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, ...)`*" - yes, it will, if used correctly. "*After I free the mutex, I can't acquire it, It just times out everytime*" - then you are using it wrong. Please [edit] your question to show your updated code.

Answer (score 2):

A semaphore is in a "signaled" state only while its counter is greater than 0. A successful wait on a semaphore decrements its counter, so `ReleaseSemaphore()` must be called afterwards to increment the counter.  The "parent" is creating the semaphore with an initial counter of 0 and not calling `ReleaseSemaphore()` to increment the counter, so that is why the `WaitForSingleObject()` in the "child" never succeeds.

When a handle to a semaphore is closed, **the semaphore's counter is not changed**. [This is documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/semaphore-objects):

> When you have finished using the semaphore object, call the `CloseHandle` function to close the handle. The semaphore object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed. **Closing the handle does not affect the semaphore count**; therefore, be sure to call `ReleaseSemaphore()` before closing the handle or before the process terminates. Otherwise, pending wait operations will either time out or continue indefinitely, depending on whether a time-out value has been specified.

Which is exactly what you are seeing happen.  You have 2 processes sharing a single semaphore object.  When the "parent" closes its handle to the semaphore (implicitly when the process exits), the semaphore still exists until the child also closes its handle to the semaphore.  But since the semaphore's counter doesn't change when the "parent" exits, the counter is never `> 0`, so the semaphore is never "signaled" to satisfy the "child"'s wait.

When you use a mutex instead, if a mutex handle is closed without calling `ReleaseMutex()` after a successful wait, the mutex becomes "abandoned" until a subsequent wait re-acquires ownership. [This is also documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects):

> **If a thread terminates without releasing its ownership of a mutex object, the mutex object is considered to be abandoned.** A waiting thread can acquire ownership of an abandoned mutex object, but the wait function will return WAIT_ABANDONED to indicate that the mutex object is abandoned. An abandoned mutex object indicates that an error has occurred and that any shared resource being protected by the mutex object is in an undefined state. If the thread proceeds as though the mutex object had not been abandoned, it is no longer considered abandoned after the thread releases its ownership. This restores normal behavior if a handle to the mutex object is subsequently specified in a wait function.

Comment: After reading, I figured out that only mutexes have abandoned coverage - as semaphores don't track references - theres no way to figure out that someone crashed without releasing. So, unlike mutexes, with semaphores you're not safe from crashes. This is the case I was trying to cover